# Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented facebook login using spring boot with security, when i try to run error occurs. I don't know from where it occurs.

how to solve this problem ? In my pom.xml already added spring-security-oauth2-client and spring-security-oauth2 dependency.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

2.WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;


    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/register", "/auth/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                .and()
                .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                .and()
                .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

3.application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        facebook:
          clientId: <clientId>
          clientSecret: <clientSecret>
          redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
          scope:
            - email
            - public_profile
        provider:
          facebook:
            authorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth
            tokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token
            userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
        app:
          auth:
            tokenSecret: 926D96C90030DD58429D2751AC1BDBBC
            tokenExpirationMsec: 864000000
          oauth2:
            authorizedRedirectUris:
              - http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect
              - myandroidapp://oauth2/redirect
              - myiosapp://oauth2/redirect
```

4.MemberServiceImpl

```
@Service(value = "userService")
public class MembersServiceImpl extends DefaultOAuth2UserService implements MembersService, UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
    private MembersDao membersDao;

@Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(oAuth2UserRequest);

        try {
            return processOAuth2User(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2User);
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Throwing an instance of AuthenticationException will trigger the OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
        }
    }

    private OAuth2User processOAuth2User(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo = OAuth2UserInfoFactory.getOAuth2UserInfo(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), oAuth2User.getAttributes());
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail())) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException("Email not found from OAuth2 provider");
        }

        Optional<Members> membersOptional = membersDao.getByEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
        Members members;
        if(membersOptional.isPresent()) {
            members = membersOptional.get();
            if(!members.getProvider().equals(AuthProvider.valueOf(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()))) {
                throw new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingException("Looks like you're signed up with " +
                        members.getProvider() + " account. Please use your " + members.getProvider() +
                        " account to login.");
            }
            members = updateExistingUser(members, oAuth2UserInfo);
        } else {
            members = registerNewUser(oAuth2UserRequest, oAuth2UserInfo);
        }

        return UserPrincipal.create(members, oAuth2User.getAttributes());
    }

    private Members registerNewUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {
        Members members = new Members();
        long roleId = 2;
        members.setProvider(AuthProvider.valueOf(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()));
        members.setProviderId(oAuth2UserInfo.getId());
        members.setFirst_name(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
        members.setEmail(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
        members.setImage(oAuth2UserInfo.getImageUrl());
        members.setRoles(new Role(roleId));
        return membersDao.save(members);
    }

    private Members updateExistingUser(Members existingUser, OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {
        existingUser.setFirst_name(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
        existingUser.setImage(oAuth2UserInfo.getImageUrl());
        return membersDao.save(existingUser);
    }

}
```

5.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private AppProperties appProperties;

    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;


    @Autowired
    OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler(TokenProvider tokenProvider, AppProperties appProperties,
                                       HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.appProperties = appProperties;
        this.httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository = httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response, authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request, response);
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        Optional<String> redirectUri = CookieUtils.getCookie(request, REDIRECT_URI_PARAM_COOKIE_NAME)
                .map(Cookie::getValue);

        if(redirectUri.isPresent() && !isAuthorizedRedirectUri(redirectUri.get())) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Sorry! We've got an Unauthorized Redirect URI and can't proceed with the authentication");
        }

        String targetUrl = redirectUri.orElse(getDefaultTargetUrl());

        String token = null;
        try {
            token = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(targetUrl)
                .queryParam("token", token)
                .build().toUriString();
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super.clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.removeAuthorizationRequestCookies(request, response);
    }

    private boolean isAuthorizedRedirectUri(String uri) {
        URI clientRedirectUri = URI.create(uri);

        return appProperties.getOauth2().getAuthorizedRedirectUris()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(authorizedRedirectUri -> {
                    // Only validate host and port. Let the clients use different paths if they want to
                    URI authorizedURI = URI.create(authorizedRedirectUri);
                    if(authorizedURI.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(clientRedirectUri.getHost())
                            && authorizedURI.getPort() == clientRedirectUri.getPort()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
    }
```

6.AppProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class AppProperties {
    private final Auth auth = new Auth();
    private final OAuth2 oauth2 = new OAuth2();

    public static class Auth {
        private String tokenSecret;
        private long tokenExpirationMsec;

        public String getTokenSecret() {
            return tokenSecret;
        }

        public void setTokenSecret(String tokenSecret) {
            this.tokenSecret = tokenSecret;
        }

        public long getTokenExpirationMsec() {
            return tokenExpirationMsec;
        }

        public void setTokenExpirationMsec(long tokenExpirationMsec) {
            this.tokenExpirationMsec = tokenExpirationMsec;
        }
    }

    public static final class OAuth2 {
        private List<String> authorizedRedirectUris = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<String> getAuthorizedRedirectUris() {
            return authorizedRedirectUris;
        }

        public OAuth2 authorizedRedirectUris(List<String> authorizedRedirectUris) {
            this.authorizedRedirectUris = authorizedRedirectUris;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public Auth getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public OAuth2 getOauth2() {
        return oauth2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should hide your clientSecret and tokenSecret (if they're real)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spring.security.oauth2.client` is the valid prefix for `OAuth2ClientProperties`. Yours is `security.oauth2.client`

UPDATE

Your `AppProperties` cannot be used for injection unless you define `@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)` on any of your `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: but one more error is occurs after changes                                                                                 Parameter 1 of constructor in com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler required a bean of type 'com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.config.AppProperties' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.config.AppProperties' in your configuration.

Comment: Do you have `OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler` definition? If you do show it please. You are missing your custom properties now.

Comment: Yes I have OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler. I had a Update my Post